# How to remove a single Attribute (e.g. ReadOnly) from a File?

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-attributes

Let say, a file has the following attributes: `ReadOnly, Hidden, Archived, System`.
**How can I remove only one Attribute?** (for example ReadOnly)

If I use the following, it removes all the attributes:

```
IO.File.SetAttributes("File.txt",IO.FileAttributes.Normal)
```

Comment: read current attributes, mask the attribute you require to set, set the attribute...

Answer (score 115, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx): You can remove any attribute like this

(but @sll's answer for just ReadOnly is better for just that attribute)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
class Test 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";

        // Create the file if it exists.
        if (!File.Exists(path)) 
        {
            File.Create(path);
        }

        FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(path);

        if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
        {
            // Make the file RW
            attributes = RemoveAttribute(attributes, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
            File.SetAttributes(path, attributes);
            Console.WriteLine("The {0} file is no longer RO.", path);
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Make the file RO
            File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
            Console.WriteLine("The {0} file is now RO.", path);
        }
    }

    private static FileAttributes RemoveAttribute(FileAttributes attributes, FileAttributes attributesToRemove)
    {
        return attributes & ~attributesToRemove;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `~` do?

Comment: @ newbieguy: That's the unary binary complement operator (aka bitwise not operator). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators

Answer (score 145):

Answering on your question in title regarding `ReadOnly` attribute:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(pathToAFile);
fileInfo.IsReadOnly = false;
```

To get control over any attribute yourself you can use [`File.SetAttributes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx) method. The link also provides an example.

Comment: this works great! but only for ReadOnly Attribute, (I know i asked for it in the title but I also need other attributes)

Comment: @qxxx: you are right, as I mentioned you have to use SetAttributes() method to modify another attributes

Comment: As a one-liner: new FileInfo(fileName) {IsReadOnly = false}.Refresh()

Comment: Is Refresh() necessary? [This example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.isreadonly(v=vs.110).aspx) suggests it isn't, and my code (admittedly with Mono) works if I don't call it.

Comment: Refresh() seems not necessary for me either.

Comment: You don't need `Refresh` here. [`IsReadOnly` is setting `Attributes`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/fileinfo.cs,37ee700f18773394), and [setting `Attributes` triggers the file system change](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filesysteminfo.cs,397d905785886f44). The state of the `FileInfo` should be up to date, so `Refresh` is redundant, so I'll go ahead and remove it, if nobody minds.

Answer (score 14):

```
string file = "file.txt";
FileAttributes attrs = File.GetAttributes(file);
if (attrs.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReadOnly))
    File.SetAttributes(file, attrs & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ((oFileInfo.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
    oFileInfo.Attributes ^= FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

Answer (score 1):

For a one line solution (provided that the current user has access to change the attributes of the mentioned file) here is how I would do it:

**VB.Net**

```
Shell("attrib file.txt -r")
```

the negative sign means to `remove` and the `r` is for read-only.
if you want to remove other attributes as well you would do:

```
Shell("attrib file.txt -r -s -h -a")
```

That will remove the Read-Only, System-File, Hidden and Archive attributes.

if you want to give back these attributes, here is how:

```
Shell("attrib file.txt +r +s +h +a")
```

the order does not matter.

**C#**

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "attrib file.txt +r +s +h +a");
```

**References**

- [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=windows+command+line+attrib)
- [ComputerHope.com](http://www.computerhope.com/attribhl.htm) - Lots of examples and OS specific notes
- [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true) - Page is for XP, but probably applies to later versions
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATTRIB) - Particularly the [Particularities section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATTRIB#Particularities)

Comment: These are not major content *changes*, they're content additions, and none of them run counter to the spirit of Stack Overflow. They're good edits, they should stay.

Comment: This seems like the equivalent of asking where to add a quart of oil to your car but being told you should take it to your dealership for an oil change.  Why execute a shell command just to flip a file attribute bit?  The answer technically works so I didn't downvote, but I did in my heart.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thanks for reviewing it, I appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <summary>
/// Addes the given FileAttributes to the given File.
/// It's possible to combine FileAttributes: FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.ReadOnly
/// </summary>
public static void AttributesSet(this FileInfo pFile, FileAttributes pAttributes)
{
    pFile.Attributes = pFile.Attributes | pAttributes;
    pFile.Refresh();
}

/// <summary>
/// Removes the given FileAttributes from the given File.
/// It's possible to combine FileAttributes: FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.ReadOnly
/// </summary>
public static void AttributesRemove(this FileInfo pFile, FileAttributes pAttributes)
{
    pFile.Attributes = pFile.Attributes & ~pAttributes;
    pFile.Refresh();
}

/// <summary>
/// Checks the given File on the given Attributes.
/// It's possible to combine FileAttributes: FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.ReadOnly
/// </summary>
/// <returns>True if any Attribute is set, False if non is set</returns>
public static bool AttributesIsAnySet(this FileInfo pFile, FileAttributes pAttributes)
{
    return ((pFile.Attributes & pAttributes) > 0);
}

/// <summary>
/// Checks the given File on the given Attributes.
/// It's possible to combine FileAttributes: FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.ReadOnly
/// </summary>
/// <returns>True if all Attributes are set, False if any is not set</returns>
public static bool AttributesIsSet(this FileInfo pFile, FileAttributes pAttributes)
{
    return (pAttributes == (pFile.Attributes & pAttributes));
}
```

Example:

```
private static void Test()
{
    var lFileInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Neues Textdokument.txt");
    lFileInfo.AttributesSet(FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
    lFileInfo.AttributesSet(FileAttributes.Temporary);
    var lBool1 = lFileInfo.AttributesIsSet(FileAttributes.Hidden);
    var lBool2 = lFileInfo.AttributesIsSet(FileAttributes.Temporary);
    var lBool3 = lFileInfo.AttributesIsSet(FileAttributes.Encrypted);
    var lBool4 = lFileInfo.AttributesIsSet(FileAttributes.ReadOnly | FileAttributes.Temporary);
    var lBool5 = lFileInfo.AttributesIsSet(FileAttributes.ReadOnly | FileAttributes.Encrypted);
    var lBool6 = lFileInfo.AttributesIsAnySet(FileAttributes.ReadOnly | FileAttributes.Temporary);
    var lBool7 = lFileInfo.AttributesIsAnySet(FileAttributes.ReadOnly | FileAttributes.Encrypted);
    var lBool8 = lFileInfo.AttributesIsAnySet(FileAttributes.Encrypted);
    lFileInfo.AttributesRemove(FileAttributes.Temporary);
    lFileInfo.AttributesRemove(FileAttributes.Hidden | FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of code in these examples, if you want a simple solution(without Shell):

```
File.SetAttributes(filepath, ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly & File.GetAttributes(filepath));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
private static FileAttributes RemoveAttribute(FileAttributes attributes, FileAttributes attributesToRemove)
```

Read detail here in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx