# Hide / Unhide a file is not working so well

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio, file

I used this to hide the file:

```
File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

But when I wanted to unhide that file, the file just got deleted, but in the code I didn't get any error, so the file is still there.

```
File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | ~FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Comment: Well.  Not working so *well*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a single Attribute (e.g. ReadOnly) from a File?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399611/how-to-remove-a-single-attribute-e-g-readonly-from-a-file)

Comment: To disable a single bit you need to use `& ~`, not `| ~`. Look for examples in the linked question. If something doesn't work for you, please, update your question with necessary details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes.aspx):

```
var attributes = File.GetAttributes(fi);
if ((attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden)
{
    attributes &= ~FileAttributes.Hidden;
    File.SetAttributes(fi, attributes);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can make a simple check with

```
bool b = File.Exists(String path)
```

Comment: And how i can unhide a file?

Comment: Maybe this what you are looking for
http://barehlacprog.blogspot.de/2012/10/c-code-to-unhidehide-files-in-windows.html