# How to detect modifications in folders via archive bit using c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

If a folder is moved or renamed in windows system ,then how can we detect the changes made to folder using c# . If archive bit on the folder is enabled, can we check it using c# and then after saving changes in database , how can i set ready for archiving flag to false once i saved the changes?

Comment: Are you aware about [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) ? What is exactly not working?

Comment: Yes, but this question is regarding folders.

Comment: @Avy, *Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a **directory**, or file in a directory, changes*

Comment: Using achieve bit is an [old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_bit) technique, it's not reliable, since anyone can change the bit.

Comment: Filesystemwatcher does not detect changes made to folders when the application is not running .

Comment: Why would you want to unset the archive flag?

Comment: @Any, nothing will monitor changes unless it's running and monitoring. What do you want to achieve? What are those folders and what is in database?

Comment: There are mutliple folders in a main fixed folder on windows system. I need to save the info of that folder and inform the server. If the application is not running and changes are made to folder when app is offline, i have to inform the db and server about all the changes once the app is executed again.

Comment: Also the same changes are to be made on different system running the same app

Comment: Sounds easy. If you don't need to monitor constantly, then simply [traverse folders](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-enumerate-directories-and-files) on startup, check their [attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes(v=vs.110).aspx), upload info and [set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes(v=vs.110).aspx)/[reset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7399611/1997232) attribute. I'd not use achieve attribute, rather ask server what was already done (local database to store such info will also do).

Comment: Thanks sinatr. The attribute does not show up in directory suggestions .

Comment: Even the set/reset attribute is not there in directory suggetions. I am using c#.